# How to listen to 'SendMail' event in Thunderbird?

Tags: c++, plugins, xul, xpcom, thunderbird

I need to intercept all mail sent by Thunderbird and block sending if there is a predefined string in the mail body. 
It should be a part of our already existing XPCOM dll addon.

Do you have any ideas how to implement it?

Comment: Block sending a predefined string?
Just wondering, why would you want that.

Comment: no reason at all :), just an example. But could be scanning for some sensitive user data, which should not go out as plaintext

Answer (score 1):

```
function send_event_handler( evt ) {

  var msgcomposeWindow = document.getElementById( "msgcomposeWindow" );

  var msg_type = msgcomposeWindow.getAttribute( "msgtype" );



  // do not continue unless this is really an actual send event

  if( !(msg_type == nsIMsgCompDeliverMode.Now || msg_type == nsIMsgCompDeliverMode.Later) )

    return;
  // do what ever you want to do here


}
// here is the listener
window.addEventListener( "compose-send-message", send_event_handler, true );
```